# Query where foreign key column can be NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, left-join

I want to get data if `orgid = 2` or if there is no row at all for the `uid`. `orgid` is an `integer`. The closest thing I could think of is to do `IS NULL` but I'm not getting data for the `uid` that doesn't have an `orgid` row. Any idea?

```
select u.uid,u.fname,u.lname from u 
inner join u_org on u.uid = u_org.uid 
inner join login on u.uid = login.uid 
where u_org.orgid=2 or u_org.orgid is NULL 
and login.access != 4;
```

Basically the `OR` is if `u_org.orgid` row doesn't exist.

Comment: My guess... you are missing parentheses? Try this instead: `(u_org.orgid = 2 OR u_org.orgid IS NULL) AND login.access != 4`

Comment: Also, you could also solve it like this: `COALESCE(u_org.orgid, 2) = 2`

Comment: @WoLpH - both didn't solve it. Maybe `IS NULL` is the wrong thing? Is it NULL if the row doesn't exist in the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is "no row at all for the uid", and you `JOIN` like you do, you get *no row* as result. Use [**`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) instead:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.fname, u.lname
FROM   u 
LEFT   JOIN u_org o ON u.uid = o.uid 
LEFT   JOIN login l ON u.uid = l.uid 
WHERE (o.orgid = 2 OR o.orgid IS NULL)
AND    l.access IS DISTINCT FROM 4;
```

Also, you need the parenthesis I added because of [**operator precedence**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE). (`AND` binds before `OR`).

I use `IS DISTINCT FROM` instead of `!=` in the last WHERE condition because, again, `login.access` might be `NULL`, which would not qualify.

However, since you only seem to be interested in columns from table `u` to begin with, this alternative query would be more elegant:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.fname, u.lname
FROM   u
WHERE (u.uid IS NULL OR EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   u_org o
   WHERE  o.uid = u.uid
   AND    o.orgid = 2
   ))
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   login l
   WHERE  l.uid = u.uid
   AND    l.access = 4
   );
```

This alternative has the additional advantage, that you always get *one* row from `u`, even if there are multiple rows in `u_org` or `login`.