# Select rows with fallback null record

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to select some records with the known `Parent` however if there is no `Child` that is associated with the given `Parent`, I'd like to retrieve the fallback records with NULLs. The result should have distinct `Childs`.

I have a table structure as

```
 Parent      Child       TITLE
--------   ---------   --------
  NULL         1        Record 1
  NULL         2        Record 2
   1           1        Record 3
```

Say the `Parent` set to `1` The expected result

```
 Parent      Child       TITLE
--------   ---------   --------
   1           1        Record 3
  NULL         2        Record 2
```

Say the `Parent` set to `2` The expected result

```
 Parent      Child       TITLE
--------   ---------   --------
  NULL         1        Record 1
  NULL         2        Record 2
```

I've tried using `JOIN` statements to get the result but I can't distinctly select the records with prioritizing non-null records. This question is somehow similar but not selecting distinctly. [Sample Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618078/query-where-foreign-key-column-can-be-null)

**EDIT**
Well, I came up with this query but I am quite sure it can be improved. I'd appreciate if you guys advice.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    DataTable
WHERE 
    DataTable.Parent = 1
UNION
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    DataTable
WHERE 
    DataTable.Parent IS NULL AND
    DataTable.Child NOT IN(
       SELECT 
          DT1.Child
       FROM 
          DataTable DT1
       WHERE 
          DT1.Parent = 1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `DataTable.Parent = 1 OR DataTable.Parent is null` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, I tried that. With that query, both null and not null values are retrieved.